# How to convert this string to a multi-dimensional list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have the next `string`:

```
string = 'tuned     1372                root    6u      REG                8,3      4096  102029349 /tmp/ffiabNswC (deleted)\ngmain     1372 2614           root    6u      REG                8,3      4096  102029349 /tmp/ffiabNswC (deleted)\n'
```

I need to put every element of the `string` into the `list1[0][..]`, but when I see a new line '\n', I have to put the next elements into `list1[1][..]`

A multi-dimensional list, like this:

```
list1 = [["tuned", "1372", "root", "6u", "REG", "8,3", "4096", "102029349", "/tmp/ffiabNswC", "(deleted)"], 
         ["gmain", "1372", "2614", "root", "6u", "REG", "8,3", "4096", "102029349", "/tmp/ffiabNswC", "(deleted)"]]
```

I do it with `split`, but it put me all in the same dimension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split first by a new line (to get the row), then split each element by space (to get each column):

```
data = "tuned 1372 root 6u REG 8,3 4096 102029349 /tmp/ffiabNswC (deleted)\ngmain 1372 2614 root 6u REG 8,3 4096 102029349 /tmp/ffiabNswC (deleted)\n"

parsed = [elements.split() for elements in data.strip().split("\n")]  # `strip()` removes the last whitespace so we don't get blank elements

print(parsed)

# [['tuned', '1372', 'root', '6u', 'REG', '8,3', '4096', '102029349', '/tmp/ffiabNswC', '(deleted)'], ['gmain', '1372', '2614', 'root', '6u', 'REG', '8,3', '4096', '102029349', '/tmp/ffiabNswC', '(deleted)']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function should do this for you:

```
f = lambda list: [sublist.split(' ') for sublist in list.split('\n')]
```

Just call it via `f(string)`.

If additionally you don't want any empty entries in your sub-lists you could do

```
f = lambda list: [sublist.split(' ') for sublist in list.split('\n') if sublist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Input:-

```
string = 'tuned 1372 root 6u REG 8,3 4096 102029349 /tmp/ffiabNswC 
(deleted)\ngmain 1372 2614 root 6u REG 8,3 4096 102029349 /tmp/ffiabNswC 
(deleted)\n'
```

Code: -  Just write

```
 mylist=string.split()
```

Output:-

```
[tuned
 1372
 root
6u
REG
8,3
4096
102029349
/tmp/ffiabNswC
(deleted)
gmain
1372
2614
root
6u
REG
8,3
4096
102029349
/tmp/ffiabNswC
(deleted)]
```

Comment: Thanks, Vic13, but I need a multidimensional list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to split the string into lines, then the lines into words, you can use a comprehension

```
result = [line.split() for line in string.split('\n')]
```

Output:

```
[['tuned', '1372', 'root', '6u', 'REG', '8,3', '4096', '102029349', '/tmp/ffiabNswC', '(deleted)'],
 ['gmain', '1372', '2614', 'root', '6u', 'REG', '8,3', '4096', '102029349', '/tmp/ffiabNswC', '(deleted)'],
 []]
```

If you don't want that final blank (because of the last `\n`) you can just `strip` it before `split`ting.

Comment: Thanks chthonicdaemon.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use list comprehensions as the following:

```
string = 'tuned     1372                root    6u      REG                8,3      4096  102029349 /tmp/ffiabNswC (deleted)\ngmain     1372 2614           root    6u      REG                8,3      4096  102029349 /tmp/ffiabNswC (deleted)\n'
print [x.split() for x in string.strip().split('\n')]
```

output:

```
[['tuned', '1372', 'root', '6u', 'REG', '8,3', '4096', '102029349', '/tmp/ffiabNswC', '(deleted)'], ['gmain', '1372', '2614', 'root', '6u', 'REG', '8,3', '4096', '102029349', '/tmp/ffiabNswC', '(deleted)']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to your help, I´ve tried to do a dictionary with the values inside a list and it´s great.

Here it is and it works. I´m starting to fall in love with list comprehension!

```
dict1 = { i.split()[0]: (i.split()[1:]) for i in data.strip().split('\n') }
```

Output:

```
dict1
{'gmain': ['1372',
 '2614',
 'root',
 '6u',
 'REG',
 '8,3',
 '4096',
 '102029349',
 '/tmp/ffiabNswC',
 '(deleted)'],
'tuned': ['1372',
 'root',
 '6u',
 'REG',
 '8,3',
 '4096',
 '102029349',
 '/tmp/ffiabNswC',
 '(deleted)']}
```